# How to map set() in object in java?

Tags: java, modelmapper

I have 1 Object in Object which has 1 set. When the data is transmitted from the API and the data is taken from the database, how can we map 2 sets<> together? Currently, I map the results at the right time at the wrong time. Because each time data is requested, set is ordered differently, which causes the order of set request and set to be skewed and the map cannot be.

Example JSON of request:

```
{
"id": "4028828d",
"facilityResults": [
    {
        "id": "4024decaa62003b",
        "value": "1",
        "note": "hau nha 656251"
    },
    {
        "id": "4028828d7f003c",
        "value": "12"
        "note": "hy 52s"
    }
]}
```

ExecuteChecklist

```java
public class ExecuteChecklist extends SiteBaseHest {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "code", length = 20)
    private String code;

    @Column(name = "area_aft", length = 100)
    private String areaAft;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "executeChecklist")
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Set<ChecklistStepRst> checklistStepRst; }
```

ExecuteChecklistUpdatesDTO

```java
public class ExecuteChecklistUpdatesDTO{

    @NotBlank(message = "id can not be null or empty")
    @Size(max = 32, message = "id length must be less than or equal 32 characters")
    private String id;

    @Size(max = 20, message = "code length must be less than or equal 20 characters")
    private String code;

    @Size(max = 100, message = "area length must be less than or equal 100 characters")
    private String areaAft;

    private Set<ChecklistStepRstUpdatesDTO> checklistStepRstUpdatesDTO; }
```

I want to map() `Set< ChecklistStepRstUpdatesDTO > checklistStepRstUpdatesDTO;` and `Set< ChecklistStepRst > checklistStepRst;`

But when JSON changes the value passed, its sort is changed. give up error :

> identifier of an instance of ... was altered from X to Y ( X to be: id, Y to be: id )

Comment: Are you saying the order should be preserved? Or the order should be in a particular order?

Comment: @Bohemian I want the data when streaming up from json to be sorted specifically and not to change, or is there another way map() between the 2 set()

Comment: What exactly does "map() between the 2 set()" mean? Please give sample input and expected output, with real code.

Answer (score 0):

@Bohemian

```
{
"id": "4028828d",
"facilityResults": [
    {
        "id": "4024decaa62003b",
        "value": "1",
        "note": "hau nha 656251"
    },
    {
        "id": "4028828d7f003c",
        "value": "12"
        "note": "hy 52s"
    }
]}
```

I map() with:

```
{
"id": "4028828d",
"facilityResults": [
    {
        "id": "4028828d7f003c",
        "value": "12",
        "note": "hy 52s"
    },
    {
        "id": "4024decaa62003b",
        "value": "1"
        "note": "hau nha 656251"
    }
]}
```

The order of facilityResults() when uploading and retrieving from the database is different and I can't map() them together